# VueJS component display other component content

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tags, vue-component

The objective: Vue component **input-address** has to be inside Vue component **mail-composer** and display a list of addresses only when someone click *Address Book* button. When someone click one of displayed mails  or fill the **To** field by hand, *createdmail.to* has to get the value and I have to hide the list of addresses.

Vue component **mail-composer**. This component receives a list of addresses. (Everything is working here, I think the only part that is not working properly is v-model inside *input-address* tag)

```
Vue.component('mail-composer', {
    props: ['addressesbook'],
    methods: {
      send: function(createmail) {
        this.$emit('send', createmail);
      }


    },
            template:
            `
            <div>
              <input-address :addresses="addressesbook" v-model="createmail.to"></input-address>
              <p><b>Subject: </b><input type="text" v-model="createmail.subject"></input></p>
              <p><b>Body: </b><textarea v-model="createmail.body"></textarea></p>
              <button @click="send(createmail)">Send</button>
            </div>
            `,
            data(){
              return{
                createmail:{
                  to: '',
                  subject: '',
                  body: ''
                }

              }
            }

      });
```

The other Vue component is this one, which is in the same file. (I think all problems are here).

I need to display the list of addresses only when someone click *Address Book* button, and I have to hide it when someone click again the button or one of the emails which are in the list. When someone clicks a mail from list, the *createmail.to* property from the **mail-composer** has to get the value of the mail , also if I decide to put the mail by hand it has to occurs the same.

```
Vue.component('input-address',{
        props:["addresses"],
        template:
        `
          <div>
          <label><b>To: </b><input type="text"></input><button @click="!(displayAddressBook)">Address Book</button></label>
          <ul v-if="displayAddressBook">
            <li  v-for="address in addresses">
            {{address}}
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        `,
        data(){
          return{
            displayAddressBook: false
          }
        }


      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're some errors in your code:

- `@click="!(displayAddressBook)"` should be `@click="displayAddressBook = !displayAddressBook"` - the first really does nothing (interesting), the second (suggested) sets the value of `displayAddressBook` to the opposite it has currently.
- the input-address component does not really do anything with the input field (missing `v-model`)
- the changes in the child component (`input-address`) are not sent back to the parent (added a `watch`er to do that in the child component)
- the parent component (`mail-composer`) has to handle the values emitted from the child (added the `@address-change` action handler)
- the `v-for` in your `input-address` component does not have a `key` set. Added `key` by using the index for it (not the best solution, but easy to do).
- just put `createmail.to: {{ createmail.to }}` at the end of `MailComposer`, so you can see how it changes

#### Suggestions

- always use **CamelCase** for component names - if you get used to it, then you get less "why is it not working?!" moments
- watch for typos: `createmail` doesn't look good - `createEmail` or just simply `createemail` would be better (ok, it doesn't look so nice - maybe you should choose a totally different name for that)

```js
Vue.component('InputAddress', {
  props: ["addresses"],
  data() {
    return {
      displayAddressBook: false,
      address: null
    }
  },
  template: `
          <div>
          <label><b>To: </b>
            <input
              type="text"
              v-model="address"
            />
            <button
              @click="displayAddressBook = !displayAddressBook"
            >
              Address Book
            </button>
          </label>
          <ul v-if="displayAddressBook">
            <li
              v-for="(address, i) in addresses"
              :key="i"
              @click="clickAddressHandler(address)"
             >
              {{address}}
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        `,
  watch: {
    address(newVal) {
      // emitting value to parent on change of the address
      // data attribute
      this.$emit('address-change', newVal)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickAddressHandler(address) {
      // handling click on an address in the address book
      this.address = address
      this.displayAddressBook = false
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('MailComposer', {
  props: ['addressesbook'],
  data() {
    return {
      createmail: {
        to: '',
        subject: '',
        body: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: function(createmail) {
      this.$emit('send', createmail);
    },
    addressChangeHandler(value) {
      this.createmail.to = value
    }
  },
  template: `
            <div>
              <input-address
                :addresses="addressesbook"
                v-model="createmail.to"
                @address-change="addressChangeHandler"
              />
              <p>
                <b>Subject: </b>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  v-model="createmail.subject"
                />
              </p>
              <p>
                <b>Body: </b>
                <textarea v-model="createmail.body"></textarea>
              </p>
              <button @click="send(createmail)">Send</button><br />
              createmail.to: {{ createmail.to }}
            </div>
            `
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    addressesbook: [
      'abcd@abcd.com',
      'fghi@fghi.com'
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <mail-composer :addressesbook="addressesbook" />
</div>
```